# Getting back both the map and the data from a request via overpass-turbo.eu

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

For a little (!) project I need to have the data (in DB) and the maps-

this request delivers the Map

```
[timeout:600];
area["ISO3166-1"="BR"]->.brazil;
area["ISO3166-1"="AR"]->.argentina;
area["ISO3166-1"="VE"]->.venezuela;
area["ISO3166-1"="PE"]->.peru;
area["ISO3166-1"="CL"]->.chile;

/* more areas..*/

(
  nwr[amenity=hospital](area.brazil);
  nwr[amenity=hospital](area.argentina);
  nwr[amenity=hospital](area.venezuela);
  nwr[amenity=hospital](area.peru);
  nwr[amenity=hospital](area.chile);
  /* other queries... */
);
out center;
```

... and this request delivers the data;

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,::lon, ::lat, "name","addr:postcode","addr:city","addr:street","addr:housenumber","contact:website"," contact:email=*")][timeout:600];
area["ISO3166-1"="BR"]->.brazil;
area["ISO3166-1"="AR"]->.argentina;
area["ISO3166-1"="VE"]->.venezuela;
area["ISO3166-1"="PE"]->.peru;
area["ISO3166-1"="CL"]->.chile;


/* more areas..*/

(
  nwr[amenity=hospital](area.brazil);
  nwr[amenity=hospital](area.argentina);
  nwr[amenity=hospital](area.venezuela);
  nwr[amenity=hospital](area.peru);
  nwr[amenity=hospital](area.chile);
  /* other queries... */
);
out center;
```

I want to have both - the map and the data. But how to achieve this? Which request gives back both?

Comment: hi there - many thanks dear Kadir Şahbaz for the editing..

Comment: You've already asked a very similar question on the German OSM Forum: https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?pid=802376#p802376 - please do a follow up there.

Comment: good day dear mmd - many thanks for the heads up. glad to hear from you. I will post a follow up here... and add all the additonal infos & findings. Thanks for your continued support